# VB.NET - app.config or what?

Tags: vb.net, app-config

Let's say I want to give a VB.NET program to my client who is technically inclined but wouldn't want to code much. I want him to be able to change/set value for a few variables. I can put these variables in app.config.

He'll then pass these on to other people who are less technically inclined than him. He doesn't want these people to change these values at all! Maybe they shouldn't be able to view them either, but viewing is acceptable, changing these values is not! Program should break if they tamper the value at all.

So how should I pass the program to him without asking him

How to accomplish something like this? I also want to make sure he doesn't have to give a lot of files to his people. How to bundle them together (using Express edition of Visual Studio/Basic 2010)?

Comment: You get this for free with Windows, only a user with admin rights can modify files in c:\program files.

Comment: @Hans Passant I don't where you got the impression from that computer admin is the guy who's supposed to be editing app.config file. :)

Comment: Maybe that could help you! I don't know if it's still a good practice by now, this is dated from 2008. http://www.dotnetprofessional.com/blog/post/2008/03/03/Encrypt-sections-of-WebConfig-or-AppConfig.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the best way to go, but something that would definitely work would be to have a binary file with all the settings, and a tool to make it user-friendly to edit, that you'd give to your client, and not the other people...

Comment: Shouldnt I just use some kind of encryption/decryption then, rather than simple binary file?

Comment: It's a possibility, however I'm not sure how you could manage a file encryption with regular text editors. If you made an app that would open the file knowing the way it's encrypted, it'd be pretty simple. I'm sure this is not the only way to get around this though.